# How to remove old UEFI boot entry?

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, uefi

Every time my computer boots, I face this GNU GRUB menu:

[image: GRUB menu]

I don't know how to remove it and every time I boot, I have to write `exit` and then I have to choose the debian entry manually.

[image: BIOS boot menu]

I've looked online and tried `sudo efibootmgr -v`

```
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,2001,3000,0005,0001,2002,2004
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,996936a8-a9d6-4eaf-8a27-9db36650aa88,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* Notebook Hard Drive - SanDisk SD8SN8U-256G-1006   BBS(HD,Notebook Hard Drive - SanDisk SD8SN8U-256G-1006,0x500)................-...........A.......................................z.......A.........................
Boot0005* debian    HD(1,GPT,996936a8-a9d6-4eaf-8a27-9db36650aa88,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC
```

and removing it using `sudo efibootmgr -b 0000 -B`, but when I restart my pc, it goes back to the GNU GRUB menu again.

I also tried changing the boot order, but it also didn't work.

How do I remove the Ubuntu UEFI boot entry?

Comment: Have you changed boot order so 0000 is not first? If that works then delete 0000 again. https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr See also `man efibootmgr` You also should remove the /EFI/ubuntu folder in the ESP - efi system partition. Make sure you keep /EFI/Boot & /EFI/grub or /EFI/debian whichever it is using.

Answer (score 4):

thanks to [oldfred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/145882/oldfred) ive solved the problem just by removing the ubuntu folder in /boot/efi/EFI